# After dissolving faces, subdivide on the face doesn't work

Tags: modeling

Try making a cube, subdiving a face, dissolving it and subdividing it again. You'll see it doesn't work. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: Could you add the exact steps on how to reproduce? I selected the top face of the default cube, subdivided it (face mode),in edge mode dissolved the edges. This can be repeated (subdivided again).

Comment: I just had the same problem on a simple cube - can't seem to recover the model so that a simple face can be subdivided again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this issue while modelling a simple Crossy Road chicken. After subdividing a face, then performing a dissolve face.

I discovered that there were vertices left behind, along the edges of the face I can no longer subdivide.

Through a process of dissolving or limited dissolving the unnecessary edges and vertices (one long run of edges at a time), I got to the position of being able to subdivide the face again.

Answer (score 3):

because it's a NGon. dissolving faces doesn't dissolve vertices. if you're in vertex mode, you'll see subdividing won't affect the face but adds vertices (and then edges). It's not a bug, your face is and continues to be a NGon.

Comment: so what do i do instead of subdividing and dissolving faces? @Bithur

Comment: it depends: what do you want to do?

Comment: well im extruding a bunch of faces, and it came out with excess faces which i dissolved, and now it won't let me subdivide so i can have the right cuts

Comment: don't use NGons too much until you understand why and how. Keep trying to have quads, or triangles and you'll be able too see how things work together. For now, try to fix your model by dissolving vertices you don't need and join those you can't dissolve (with J) to make quads and tris

Comment: does it have to do with the "dot" marking the face not being centered?

Comment: j isn't working in edit mode? how do i make a bunch of lined up vertices delete so that only the ones that are actual creases stay?

Comment: to be short : dots are vertices (vertex when only 1), an edge is the line between 2 vertices, a face is made of at least 3 vertices (tri) making a surface. Faces can have 3 (tri) 4 (quad) or more (NGon) vertices.

Comment: you'd better see basic tutorials to understand what to do. http://cgcookie.com/blender/  http://www.blenderguru.com/

Comment: i know how blender works, basically, but what about my question?

Comment: which one? for the real original question, you have the answer.

Comment: I know how blender works! I just don't understand why dissolving vertices between other lined up vertices makes the face go crazy.

Comment: don't know what you mean, dissolving a vertice between other lined up vertices just make the "dot" disapear...

Answer (score 0):

I also dissolved edge and after a while I needed to subdivide that face I dissolved edge from. It did not work.
So, all I did was selecting 2 vertices and connect themselves by Mesh -> Vertices -> Connect Vertex Path and it created a edge across the problematic face :)
Hope I answered properly your issue.